# Dynamic Ansible SSH key management

Tags: ansible

I'm creating an ansible role to manage user SSH keys dyanmically. The general idea is to have it read all of the `files/*.pub` files in that directory and combine them into a single `authorized_keys` file for the root user.

In the example below, `a.pub` and `b.pub` would be the two keys to add. The task should add both of these to the `authorized_keys` file, and keep the list of `.pub` files here in sync with the files as they are added and removed. So if a `c.pub` is added to the folder, it would be added to the `authorized_keys` file without modifying the task.

Role structure:

```
/-- roles
|   |-- ssh
|   |   |-- files
|   |       |-- a.pub
|   |       |-- b.pub
|   |-- tasks
|       |-- main.yml
|-- site.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is the [`fileglob` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/fileglob.html) and would be used as:

```
- name: ensure authorized keys
  authorized_key:
    exclusive: yes
    key: >
       {% for fn in lookup("fileglob", "files/*.pub") %}
       {{ lookup("file", fn) }}
       {% endfor %}
    # ... whatever other options you want
```